# How to return 8 decimal place trander_bbands() ? php_trader

Tags: php

I am sending an array with prices of up to 8 decimal places, but the trader_bbands function returns me a vector float with up to 3 decimal places, what can I do to return 8 decimal places? Thank you!

[image]

My code:

```
    $result = trader_bbands($arr, 21, 2.0, 2.0, TRADER_MA_TYPE_EMA);
    $upper_band = end($result[0]);
    $medium = end($result[1]);
    $lower_band = end($result[2]);

    echo '<pre>';
    var_dump($lower_band, $result);
    echo '</pre>';
    die();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I discovered another easier solution if someone has the same problem:

```
ini_set('trader.real_precision', '8');
$result = trader_bbands($arr, 21, 2.0, 2.0, TRADER_MA_TYPE_EMA);
```

Comment: Do you know what the time period param actual means? What time period??? Why do you use 21?

Comment: Hello, period means quantity in days, read more in the articles on bollinger bands.